# Azure - Blob Storage - Mixing Custom Domain with SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Storage account that hosts a static web site as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website). This means the static web site "lives" in a storage container named `$web`. This web site is accessible via a custom domain. This is currently working as desired. However, there is one file that I want to restrict access to.

There is one file in the `$web` storage container that I only want individuals to access if a) they have a key and b) it's during a specific time window. My thinking was that I could accomplish this with a [Shared Access Signature (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview). However, while testing this approach, it doesn't seem to work. It seems that everything in the `$web` storage container is publicly visible whether a SAS has been generated or not. Is this correct?

Is there a way to require that a file in the `$web` storage container have an SAS? Or, do I need to "host" the file in a separate storage container (thus removing it from my custom domain)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When visit the files stored in `$web` container via `primary static website endpoint`(for example, `https://contosoblobaccount.z22.web.core.windows.net/index.html`), the files are always be accessible whether the container is public or private. So it doesn't matter the `sas token` is specified or not.

And the `sas token` only take effects if the `$web` container is private access, and people visit it via `primary blob service endpoint`(For example, `https://contosoblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$web/index.html`).

Please refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#impact-of-the-setting-the-public-access-level-of-the-web-container) for more details.

So for your purpose, you should put it in another container with private access.